# Derivative of $n^{1/2}$

Tags: derivatives

Why the derivative of 
$n^{1/2}$

is 
$
\frac{1}{2} n^{-1/2} \frac{dn}{dt}
$
??
I understand the first part but why the $ \frac{dn}{dt}
$ part?

I looked online and i saw that it uses the property for complex functions,

$
 u^{ν}= νu^{ν-1} u'
$.

But why is the $
\frac{1}{2}
$ considered something complex?

The i looked up Wolfram Alpha and gotten these results which makes things even weirder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try typing in Wolfram Alpha  d x(t)^(1/2)/dt

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is a function of $t$, hence $n=n(t)$, then, by the chain rule the derivative of $n(t)^{1/2}$ is

$$ \frac{1}{2 n(t)^{1/2}}n'(t).$$

Answer (score 2):

Here $n$ is supposed to be a function of $t$. The derivative of $n^{1/2}$ w.r.t. $n$ is $\frac 1 2 n^{-1/2}$ but the derivative w.r.t. $t$ is $\frac 1 2 n^{-1/2} \frac {dn} {dt}$ by Chain Rule.